# How to Sort one collection based on another one and other condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list which I want to sort:

```cs
List<string> temp = {
    "Mina 1", "Mina 2", 
    "Planning 3", "Planning 2", "Planning 1", "Planning 4", 
    "Kira 2", "Kira 1"};
```

List to sort:

```cs
// Sort items based on the following order of name
List<string> listToSort= {"Planning", "Mina", "Kira" };
```

I'm trying to sort temp based on listToSort and number increase

expected Result:

```cs
List<string> temp = {
    "Planning 1", "Planning 2", "Planning 3", "Planning 4",
    "Mina 1", "Mina 2",  
    "Kira 1", "Kira 2"};
```

Comment: Which problems do you face when trying? It's not clear where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are lists you can use a combination of [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0) and [`StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0):

```cs
var result = temp
    .OrderBy(t => listToSort.FindIndex(s => s.StartsWith(t)))
    .ThenBy(t => t);
```

Answer (score 1):

While not the most efficient, one option is to use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0):

```
var sorted = listToSort.SelectMany(sortKey => temp.Where(t => t.StartsWith(sortKey)).OrderBy(s => s));
```

For every string in `listToSort`, `SelectMany` finds all related string in `temp` and orders by them.

If you need natural sorting (so "Kira 11" will be sorted after "Kira 9"), you can add a comparer, for example [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048016/7586)